# Google Chrome does not render progress bar till series of XHR calls are complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, salesforce

Added a progress bar (bootstrap) in a toastrjs to a Salesforce.com custom button on a list view that executes remote apex. The remote apex is executed in a for loop, for each selected record in the list view. The progress bar width is being updated after each call, to show progress of the task.

The toastr/progressbar is not displayed till all xhr calls are completed, when all toastrs are displayed at once.

Noticed in the Chrome inspector that the rendering is "rasterized" only after the remote calls are completed.

1) Is this expected behaviour for Google Chrome?
2) Is there a work-around to ensure the toastr/progressbar are updated after each xhr call?

Thanks!

Comment: I know... should [use a VF page instead of custom button](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/5246/4550). But wanted to figure out why the display wasn't being updated. Also, wanted to show the progress without navigating away from the list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Hope this helps others with the same issue.

Works if using async XHR. Refer this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/5301/4550) for how to setup the callbacks.

Chrome (and maybe other browsers?) defers the "rasterization"(actually painting the pixels on the display!!) till the for loop with xhr calling the apex method is completed. If the progressbar update is done within the loop, you will see the results only after the loop ends.

By moving the progressbar update into a callback:

1. all the xhrs are queued up in the beginning (when progress is zero),
2. initial progressbar is displayed, and
3. as each xhr succeeds(or fails) the progressbar is updated.

See the [codepen](http://codepen.io/rkaramch/pen/QyeXWg) for an example of how this would be done in a pure javascript+xhr([createCORSRequest](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)) scenario.

```
for(i = 0; i < total; i++) {
  xhr = createCORSRequest(method, url);
  xhr.onload = function() {
    // Success code goes here.
    done++;
    processbarupdate(done / total * 100);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function() {
    // Error code goes here.
    done++;
    processbarupdate(done / total * 100);
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```